# Base 64 encode image. Upload twitter avatar

Tags: php, twitter, base64

I'm trying to make an image upload form for twitter to change avatar. Twitter says the image has to be base 64 encoded before I upload it. So here's a sample

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/account/update_profile_image

How can I do this so far I've been getting errors

PHP Code:

```
<?php // process form data 
    if ($_POST['image']){ 
        // post profile update 
        $post_data = array( 
            "image" => $_POST['image'] 
        ); 

         $post_data = base64_encode($post_data); 

        echo $post_data; 
        } 
        else{ 
        echo     
        "  <form action='post.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
<br><input type='hidden' name='image' value='update_profile_image'> 

    <input type='file' name='image' size='30'/><br> 

    <input type='submit' value='Upload' class='button'/> 


    </form>";} 

    ?>
```

Please help

Comment: what is in the variable `$im` and where is it set?

Comment: base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\php\post.php on line 7

Comment: why are you using $_POST for fetching files ?, instead you should be using $_FILES to retrieve files such as your image. check @Michael solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of this, you aren't retrieving the image from the POST at all. The image itself will be available in `$_FILES`

```
// See what's in $_FILES
var_dump($_FILES);

// You need the temporary name of your image from $_FILES
$filedata = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$post_data = base64_encode($filedata);

// Now you should have a base64 ascii string
echo $post_data;
```

Comment: Ive tried this. Every Image I upload gives me the same base 64 code

Comment: @boobieee Sorry - I forgot to get the actual file binary data with `file_get_contents()`.  See change above.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.
Move the uploaded file to a directory because you cannot get required results by encrypting the [tmp_name]

```
if ($_FILES['image']){

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "path" .basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]));
$meh = file_get_contents("path/" .basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]));
$results = base64_encode($meh);
}
```